# How would I find the solutions for $AX = 0?$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

\begin{pmatrix}4&-6&2&-6\\ \:-2&3&-1&3\end{pmatrix}

Am I supposed to move the $0 $ to the other side of the equation and find the inverse of the matrix above or is there another way?

Comment: You can't even invert this matrix - it isn't square! Hint: just use row reduction to try to find a basis for the kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are solving for the kernel of the matrix
\begin{pmatrix}4&-6&2&-6\\ \:-2&3&-1&3\end{pmatrix}
which is the same as solving the augmented system 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}4&-6&2&-6&0\\ \:-2&3&-1&3&0\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow
\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&0&0\\ \:-2&3&-1&3&0\end{pmatrix}
$$
from which we find that we have 3 degrees of freedom. Namely, we need only to make sure 
$$
x=\frac32w-\frac32y-\frac12z
$$
and any input of $w,y,z$ will do. Encoding this, we name $y=s,z=t,w=r$ and find that 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}3/2r-3/2s-1/2t\\s\\t\\r\end{pmatrix}=
r\begin{pmatrix}3/2\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}+s\begin{pmatrix}-3/2\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}+t\begin{pmatrix}-1/2\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}
$$
and the vectors with the coefficients $r,t,s$ span your kernel.

Answer (score 0):

A $4\times 2$ matrix **can not have** an inverse. You are searching for the kernel of $A$. With a few [Gauss moves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) on the rows of $A$ you can simplify the sistem $A·x = 0$ getting the solutions. In this case the solution set, $\ker{A}$, is a subspace of dimension $2$, a plane, in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: I believe it should be of dimension 3 since the two rows are redundant

Comment: Was too fast to see at the rows (and too trusting probability for betting on a almost false event)

Comment: non ce problema. Mi pareva solo giusto notarlo!

Comment: Did you guessed my spaghetti-eating nature from my name?

Comment: The OP has a $2 \times 4$ matrix, but your point still stands.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I invoke $rkA= rk(A^t)$

Answer (score 0):

Simply row reduce the coefficient matrix and let your independent variables (columns without leading ones) be your parameters. Being a homogenous system with 2 equations and 4 variables you will have infinite solutions (since every homogenous system has at least the trivial solution)

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 variables and 2 equations. This implies that you have infinitly many solutions.